# Sprite doesn't appear on the screen when states are passed by reference

Tags: c++, sfml

This code works fine

```
class ASpriteNode : public ASceneNode {
public:
    explicit        ASpriteNode( const sf::Texture& texture );
                    ASpriteNode( const sf::Texture& texture, const sf::IntRect& rect );

private:
    virtual void    drawCurrent( sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states ) const;

    sf::Sprite      sprite;
};
```

But if I change line to

```
virtual void    drawCurrent( sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates& states ) const;
```

then sprite will not appear on the screen.

WHY?

Comment: Why do you want to pass the states by reference? Also, please provide a minimal code sample inside your question.

Comment: Did you change the change the signature of every `drawCurrent` in the class hierarchy or only the one in `ASpriteNode`?

Comment: I am passing by value just simple types like `float`. Anything else I am passing by reference. Or by reference to constant, if I can. I've spent days trying to understand, what was wrong.

Comment: seems like in one derived class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Stephan pointed out in a comment, the issue arises because you only changed the function signature of `drawCurrent` in one derived class. This makes the changed `ASpriteNode::drawCurrent` an **overload** of the `ASceneNode::drawCurrent` virtual function, but it doesn't **override** `ASceneNode::drawCurrent` anymore. So when `ASceneNode::drawCurrent` is called, `ASpriteNode::drawCurrent` is not called anymore.

You need to change `ASceneNode::drawCurrent`, and all classes derived from `ASceneNode`, to the new signature:

```
class ASceneNode {
    ....
    virtual void drawCurrent( sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates& states ) const;
    ....
};

class ASpriteNode : public ASceneNode {
    ....
    virtual void drawCurrent( sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates& states ) const;
    ....
};
```

Comment: It took several days to find out where I made mistake. Thanks a lot for explaining *what* and *why* was wrong.